# Kafka repartitioning

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

From my understanding partitions and consumers are tied up into a 1:1 relationship in which a single consumer processes a partition. However is there such a way to repartition in the middle of processing?
We are currently trying to optimize a process in which the topic gets consumed across a group but there are cases in which the data processing needs to take longer on a certain consumer while others are already idle. Its like data cleansing where a certain partition might no longer need cleansing while others require fuzzy matching thereby adding complexity to the task a consumer performs.

Answer (score 9):

Your understanding with regards to partitions and consumers is not quite right.

If you have N partitions, then you can have up to N consumers within the same consumer group each of which reading from a single partition. When you have less consumers than partitions, then some of the consumers will read from more than one partition. Also, if you have more consumers than partitions then some of the consumers will be inactive and will receive no messages at all.

If you have one consumer per partition, then some of the partitions might receive more messages and this is why some of your consumers might be idle while some others might still processing some messages. Note that messages are not always inserted into topic partitions in a round-robin fashion as messages with the same key are placed into the same partition.

Comment: So are you saying that the number of partitions should be increased? Right messages are evenly distributed across the partitions.

Comment: I am not saying that the number of partitions should be increased. I tried to explain how things work in Kafka with regards to consumers, consumer groups and partitions.

Answer (score 3):

in kafka topics are partitioned, and even if you can add partitions to a topic there is no repartitioning: all the data already written to a partition stays there, new data will be partitioned among the existing partitions (in a round robin fashion if you do not define keys, otherwise one key will always land in the same partition as long as you do not add partitions.)

But if you have a consumer group, and you add or remove consumers to this group, there is a group rebalancing where each consumer receives its share of partitions to exclusively consume from.

So if you have 3 partitions (with evenly distributed messages among them) and 2 consumers (in the same group) one consumer will have twice as much messages to handle than the other; with 3 consumers each one will consume one partition; with 4 consumers one will stay idle...

So as you already have evenly distributed messages (which is good), you should have as many consumers as you have partitions, and if it is still not fast enough you may add n partitions and n consumers. (For sure you could also try to optimize the consumer but that is another story...)

**Added to answer comment:**

Once a consumer -- from a given group -- is consuming a partition, it will continue to do so and will be the only one from the group consuming this partition, even if a lot of other consumers from the same group are idle. In one group a partition is never shared between consumers. (If the consumer crashes, another one will continue the work, and if a new consumer enters the group a rebalance will occur, but anyway only one consumer will work on one partition at a given time).

So one approach, as said in your comment would be to distribute the load evenly over the partitions. Another approach, would be to have a topic dedicated to expensive jobs, let it have a lot of partitions and a lot of consumers; and let the topic for non-expensive jobs have fever consumers.

Last approach that I would not recommend would be to not use the consumer group features and to manage yourself how you consume from Kafka, by using assign and seek methods from the consumer. (See [KafkaConsumer JavaDoc](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) for more information). Spark Structured Streaming for example is using that approach, but it is much more complex...

Comment: Yeah the problem is basically the consumers are finishing the tasks in an unpredictable manner. What can you suggest so that the partitions can be redistributed among idle consumers? We are looking into creating various topics and applying filters so that the "complicated" ones are not bunched up together.